# WordPress: Non-existent pages are being loaded

Tags: wordpress, apache, server

I believe a hacker modified the website 'http://bbltechnical.co.uk/' so that loads of dating website show up in Google search results for the website. I have looked for those posts/pages via the dashboard and database, and the don't seem to be anywhere.

**(I warn further click-through links on the following page contain explicit content)**

Example spam page: http://bbltechnical.co.uk/online-uk-dating/

You can see I have changed the theme of the actual website, yet the theme hasn't changed on the spam pages. Using Wappalyzer I have found the WordPress versions differ. Also the two images in the body text of that page do not exist on the FTP. So I have concluded it is another WordPress set up, sharing the same domain name.

I have cleared the database, flushed out the DNS records, and even spoken to GoDaddy about it. It is such a weird behaviour.

This is the `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: So what did your provider reply about the reason?

Comment: Anyway, the first thing to do is _remove_ that WP installation, it is infected anyway. Do a fresh install. Your installation acts as a proxy zombie. WP is well known for such things, it isn't exactly "robust" solution...

Comment: Nevertheless you should examine how this could happen. Somehow the attacker must have been able to modify files on your system such that it executes your code. How can that be? Could it be that you stored the WP files such that the web server process can write them? That would explain a lot ;-)

Comment: @arkascha They spent over an hour looking at it, and gave up saying they weren't versed enough in WordPress to fix it. I'll try that +1

Comment: It is not your providers task or responsibility to fix your files or installation! _You_ are responsible for that.

Comment: If possible, do a clean install, or use sucuri security plugin or wordfence plugin to detect changes in wordpress core files.

Comment: @arkascha Well I initially got in contact with them thinking it was sneaky DNS record addition

Comment: Those are all things you can check yourself. What IP address does your domain / host name resolve to? Is that the correct one or not? Then you know if you are looking at DNS poisoning or not.

Comment: uvishere Thank you so much! It was a modification of 'wp-blog-header.php'. arkascha Thank you for the help. Do you guys think I should close this question or add the plugin suggestion as an answer to help others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it was a modification of 'wp-blog-header.php', at the root of the site, which edited the HTTP header to pull in data from another website.

I used a malware scanner plugin to scan for any changes to the core WordPress files.

> Thanks to uvishere's suggestion, I used the plugin '[Sucuri Security](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sucuri-scanner/)' to scan for the changes. Another option is the plugin '[Wordfence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/)'.